# Flutter Bloc Test: Unexpected State Change After Multiple Events

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, bloc

I'm currently facing an issue with Flutter Bloc testing where I have a sequence of events: fetching items, then decrementing the item count. The problem is that the expected state after the decrement is not matching the actual state. It seems like the item count is being decremented from the initial state instead of the state after fetching the items.

In my case, I have a single state class which uses copyWith function.  In state response list remains same from GetCartItem to decrement in the bloc.stream getting data. When I call two events one after another, like 'get items' event then than 'decremented count'.
Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
    class MockRepository extends Mock implements Repository {}
    
    void main() {
      late MockRepository mockRepository;
    
      setUp(() {
        mockRepository = MockRepository();
      });
      
        blocTest<TestBloc, ItemState>(
        'emits correct states when decrementing the cart item count and updating cart items',
        setUp: () {
          when(() => mockRepository.getCartItemList()).thenAnswer(
                (_) async => [
              ItemEntity(
                id: 1,
                productName: 'Product 1',
                productPrice: '10.00',
                cartItemCount: 2,
              ),
            ],
          );
          when(() => mockRepository.updateCartItem(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
        },
        build: () => TestBloc(repository: mockRepository),
        act: (bloc) {
          bloc.add(GetCartItemListEvent());
          bloc.add(DecrementCartItemEvent(1));
        },
        expect: () => [
          ItemState(status:  CallbackStatus.loading,total: 0.0),
          ItemState(status: CallbackStatus.success,
              response:[ItemEntity(
                id: 1,
                productName: 'Product 1',
                productPrice: '10.00',
                cartItemCount: 2,
              )],total: 20.0),
          ItemState(status: CallbackStatus.initial,
              response:[ItemEntity(
                id: 1,
                productName: 'Product 1',
                productPrice: '10.00',
                cartItemCount: 2,
              )],total: 20.0),
          ItemState(status: CallbackStatus.loading,
              response: [
                ItemEntity(
                  id: 1,
                  productName: 'Product 1',
                  productPrice: '10.00',
                  cartItemCount: 2,
                ),
              ], total: 20.0),
          ItemState(status: CallbackStatus.initial, response: [
            ItemEntity(
              id: 1,
              productName: 'Product 1',
              productPrice: '10.00',
              cartItemCount: 1,
            )
          ], total: 10.0),
        ],
      );
      
    }
```

Error shows

```
    Expected: [
    ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.loading, null, 0.0),
    
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.success, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 2}], 20.0),
    
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.initial, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 2}], 20.0),
    
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.loading, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1,productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 2}], 20.0),
    
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.initial, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 1}], 10.0)
          ]
    
    Actual: [
    ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.loading, null, 0.0),
    
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.success, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 1}], 20.0),
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.initial, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 1}], 20.0),
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.loading, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 1}], 20.0),
            ItemState:ItemState(CallbackStatus.initial, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 1}], 10.0)
          ]
    
    Which: at location [1] is ItemState:<ItemState(CallbackStatus.success, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 1}], 20.0)> instead of ItemState:<ItemState(CallbackStatus.success, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 2}], 20.0)>
```

```
==== diff ========================================
```

```
    [ItemState(CallbackStatus.loading, null, 0.0),
    ItemState(CallbackStatus.success, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: [-2-]{+1+}}], 20.0),
    ItemState(CallbackStatus.initial, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: [-2-]{+1+}}], 20.0),
    ItemState(CallbackStatus.loading, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: [-2-]{+1+}}], 20.0),
    ItemState(CallbackStatus.initial, [ItemEntity{id: 1, productName: Product 1, productPrice: 10.00, cartItemCount: 1}], 10.0)]
```

```
==== end diff =================================================================
```

The issue is that the actual state after the second event shows the item count decremented from the initial state, but it should be from the state after fetching items.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!